# binding ng-model value into http parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am trying to show the weather of any location based on user input. For that I have created an input field which takes any location as an input. For that I have used `ng-model` directive to bind the user input and place it in $http parameter field.

The app was supposed to do was show the weather based on the user input.  I would be grateful if anybody could look into my code and tell me what I did wrong.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">

    <form>
      Location: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.location" value="Paris">
      <button type="button" ng-click=submit()>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h1>{{ vm.data| json}}</h1>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {

  var vm = this;     

  $scope.submit = function(){

    var URL = 'https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json';
    var request = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: URL,
      params: { 
        q: vm.location,
        mode:'json',
        cnt:'7',
        units:'imperial',
        key:'1a17370dc8e34f09946231209170404' 
      }
    }; 

    $http(request)
      .then(function(response) {
        vm.data = response.data;            
      }).
      catch(function(response) {
        vm.data = response.data;
      });
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the controller is instantiated with "controllerAs" syntax, don't use `$scope`, use the `this` context.

In the template:

```html
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
   <form>
      ̶L̶o̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶:̶ ̶<̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶"̶t̶e̶x̶t̶"̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶l̶o̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶"̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶P̶a̶r̶i̶s̶"̶>̶
      Location: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.location" value="Paris">
      ̶<̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶"̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶"̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶s̶u̶b̶m̶i̶t̶(̶)̶>̶S̶u̶b̶m̶i̶t̶<̶/̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶>̶
      <button type="button" ng-click=vm.submit()>Submit</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var vm = this;

̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶s̶u̶b̶m̶i̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶{̶
vm.submit = function() {    
    var URL = 'https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json';
    var request = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: URL,
      params: { 
        //q:'vm.location',
        //USE variable
        q: vm.location,
        mode:'json',
        cnt:'7',
        units:'imperial',
        key:'1a17370dc8e34f09946231209170404' 
      }
};
```

---

> Could you explain why is it `vm.location` and not only `location` in ng-model directive?

When controllers are instantiated with "controllerAs" syntax, the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) binds the `this` context of the controller to a property of the `$scope` object with the specified name. To reference properties of the controllers `this` context, the template should prefix those property names with the name specified in the "controllerAs" binding.

The AngularJS team recommends following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) — watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with `ng-switch`.

For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki - Understanding Scopes.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: Thanks a lot @georgeawg. Could you explain why is it "vm.location" and not only "location" in ng-model directive?